# unable to see the changed files in git from branchA in new BranchB

Tags: git, gerrit, cherry-pick

Team, my need to copy all the changed files from BranchA (unmerged but pushed to remote) to new BranchB. so I did below

```
git checkout old-change-1947545
git branch -c BranchB
vi src/test.py (add a print line)
git add src/test.py
git commit -m "changes from old-change-1947545 and my new changed file test.py"
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/main
```

What am observing is that the new branch is only showing src/test.py and it not showing me files that were changed in old-change-1947545
what did i miss?

Comment: How are you comparing BranchB?

Comment: There seems to be details missing here. The question is tagged cherry-pick but there are nothing in the question that implies that anything is cherry-picked.